# Usar Javascript para criar vários input com ids diferentes automaticamente

Tags: php, javascript, post

Estou montando um sistema que recebe números e depois os passa para um form, até ai esta tudo funcionando bem, consigo gerar um ou mais input com o valor que eu desejo, meu problema é que quando envio o formulário e recebo os dados na pagina php ele só esta pegando o valor de 1 input, ignorando os outros, teria uma forma de ao gerar esses input no javascript acrescentar um numero na frente do id e name?

Estou usando assim:

```
<input type=\'hidden\' name=\'numeros\' id=\'numeros\' value=\''+MeuNumero(value)+'\'>
```

A pagina php que recebe os dados esta assim:

```
if (isset($_POST["action"])){ 

   $nome=$_POST["nome"]; 
   $telefone=$_POST["telefone"]; 
   $numeros=$_POST["numeros"]; 


   echo "<p>Olá, ".$nome."</p>"; echo "<p>Os números escolhidos são: ".$numeros."</p>"; 

   echo "<p>Seu telefone é: ".$telefone."</p>"; 

}
```

Ele cria um input pra cada numero selecionado, porem com mesmo atributo name e id, assim:

```
<input type="hidden" name="numeros" id="numeros" value="10">
<input type="hidden" name="numeros" id="numeros" value="11">
<input type="hidden" name="numeros" id="numeros" value="12">
```

Gostaria que a cada novo input criado ele colocasse um número na frente do atributo name e id, ficando assim:

```
<input type="hidden" name="numeros1" id="numeros1" value="10">
<input type="hidden" name="numeros2" id="numeros2" value="11">
<input type="hidden" name="numeros3" id="numeros3" value="12">
```

etc...

E depois receber na pagina php todos os inputs que o javascript criar, que vai ser de 1 até no máximo 10 inputs. Já tenho uma trava que não deixa a pessoa selecionar mais do que 10 números por vez.

Desse jeito que fiz ele cria os inputs com o valor selecionado, porem quando resgato esses inputs na pagina php ele só mostra o primeiro resultado.

Não sei se fui claro, é que não encontrei o termo técnico para usar, sei que em programação da pra fazer algo como: **i++** . Bom tentei deixar o mais claro possível dentro da minha ignorância. Agradeço a todos que puderem ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fala Marko blz?
Existe uma solução bastante simples.

1. Crie os names na forma de array no html. 
   Você resgata no PHP com o nome da variável `$numeros` como um array.
2. Se os IDs forem mesmo necessários, pode utilizar o próprio valor (do campo value) como id.

Eles ficarão assim:

```
<input type="hidden" name="numeros[]" id="num-10" value="10">
<input type="hidden" name="numeros[]" id="num-11" value="11">
<input type="hidden" name="numeros[]" id="num-12" value="12">
```

```
//No PHP
$numeros = $_POST['numeros'];

$numeros[0];
$numeros[1];
...
```

Abraços!

Comment: Muito obrigado Tiago, deu certo.